# Sort multiple columns of Table VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to filter 3 columns alphabetically (A to Z) of a table, but am having a hard time doing that. My first try I recorded a macro that does that but because the table is has multiple columns I got some issues with some formulas that were not calculating correctly, so I thought of specifying the range of my table:

```vb
Sub trieNameCenterStatus()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")

    ' Find the last row in the table
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Define the entire range of the table
    Dim tableRange As Range
    Set tableRange = ws.Range("A3:IH" & lastRow)

    ' Apply AutoFilter to the entire table range
    tableRange.AutoFilter

    ' Clear existing sort fields
    ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

    ' Apply sorting on the entire table, focusing on specific columns
    With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("M3:M" & lastRow), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("D3:D" & lastRow), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("F3:F" & lastRow), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange tableRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

The errors am getting change but mostly here: `.SetRange tableRange`

This code does it:

```vb
Sub trieNameCenterStatus()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")

    ' Find the last row in the table
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    ' Define the entire range of the table for sorting
    Dim sortRange As Range
    Set sortRange = ws.Range("A3:IH" & lastRow)

    ' Define the range for the keys (columns M, D, and F)
    Dim keyRange1 As Range, keyRange2 As Range, keyRange3 As Range
    Set keyRange1 = ws.Range("M3:M" & lastRow)
    Set keyRange2 = ws.Range("D3:D" & lastRow)
    Set keyRange3 = ws.Range("F3:F" & lastRow)

    ' Apply multi-level sorting
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
      
        .SortFields.Add Key:=keyRange1, Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=keyRange2, Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=keyRange3, Order:=xlAscending
        
        

        .SetRange sortRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

But the problem is the button for filtering that is normally bellow the headers of columns disappeared for all the columns except A to M.

Comment: If you have an actual table, they have their own `Sort` object.

Comment: It's not a table, just gets the data using a query

Comment: What kind of query doesn't return a table?

Comment: I checked in Table Design, when i select the table range it doesn't have a name

Comment: If you can see Table Design, you must be in a table...

Comment: Either leave the `.SetRange tableRange` out since it should already know what range to apply this to with the set Autofilter or leave out the `.AutoFilter` between ws and .Sort. Edit: seems like you found it.

Comment: But there is no name under : Table Name. I edited my question, am just a beginner so there a lot of things that I need to learn

Comment: Can you help me please appear the filtering buttons, without impacting the sort ?